# Why is the vuex component isn't updated, despite the state updating?

Tags: components, vue.js, vuex

When I load my page, I fetch a list of [`optboxes` items](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/tree/eb236f4e004e3b8cc492929c4ef10b1ddfaeec42/frontend/src/pages/optboxes/optboxes.vue).

#### Sources

Project's sources are online:

- [`optboxes` page](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/tree/eb236f4e004e3b8cc492929c4ef10b1ddfaeec42/frontend/src/pages/optboxes/optboxes.vue) ;
- [store](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/tree/eb236f4e004e3b8cc492929c4ef10b1ddfaeec42/frontend/src/store) (store, actions, mutations, getters).

#### `optboxes` pages

The HTTP request is well send and return adequate data:

```
created(){
    this.getOptboxes();
},
components: {
    'optbox': OptboxComponent,
},
methods: {
    getOptboxes() {
        optboxes.all().then((response) => {
            this.setOptboxes(response.data.output);
    }).catch(() = > {
            this.no_optbox_message = 'there is no optbox';
        logging.error(this.$t('optboxes.get.failed'))
    });
    }
},
vuex: {
    actions: { setOptboxes: actions.setOptboxes},
    getters: { optboxesList: getters.retrieveOptboxes}
}
```

I'm iterating over the results as follow:

```
<div v-for="optbox in optboxesList" class="panel panel-default">
     <optbox :optbox="optbox"></optbox>
</div>
```

#### Store

```
const state = {
    optboxes: {
        /*
        'akema': {
            hostname: "192.168.2.23",
            id: "akema",
            printers: [
                {
                    description: "bureau",
                    destination_port: 9100,
                    forward: "normal",
                    hostname: "1.2.3.4",
                    id: 0,
                    listening_port: 9102
                }
            ]
        }
        */
    }
};
```

#### Question

If I switch to another pages and come back then the list appear. I also notice that with the Vuex extension I can commit the state and see the changes.

**Why are my changes not applied automatically?**

Answer (score 5):

I had to change my data structure due to [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

> Due to limitations of JavaScript, Vue.js **cannot** detect the following
>   changes to an Array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[0] = {};`
> - When you modify the length of the Array, e.g. `vm.items.length = 0`.

#### Store

`optboxes` is now an array.

```
const state = {
    optboxes:[]
}
```

Then update my mutations accordingly to edit the array.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's an issue of reactivity?! I assume your setOptboxes mutation is not being picked up by vue:

```
setOptboxes(state, optboxes) {
    for (var optbox of optboxes) {
        state.optboxes[optbox.id] = optbox;
    }
}
```

You can read about it here:

https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats

https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html

The docs solution is to use:

```
state.optboxes.$set(optbox.id, optbox);
```

which will trigger a view update.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but `state.optboxes` is not an `Array` but an `Object`. Using the `$set()` approach fail my promise

Answer (score 4):

Using `Vue.set` dit it for me. Take a look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)